# Refresh MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, page-refresh

I have a little app that initially requests a user id.  This user id is then sent as a parameter to a stored procedure that returns values from a database.  What I would like for this app to do is to refresh those same values every 30 seconds.  My issue is that when I refresh, I lose the user id.  Is there something simple that I'm missing here?

```
public ActionResult Report()
{

  string operatorCode = Request.Form.GetValues("txtOperator")[0].ToString();

  ViewBag.operatorName = (from e in db.employees
                          where e.operator_code == operatorCode
                          select e.name).Max().ToString();            

  ViewData["operatorCode"] = operatorCode;            

  var results =  db.lex_sp_Select_Paintline_FinRew_Operator(operatorCode);

  Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "10");

  return View(results.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main reason for the null value is due to the fact that you are trying to refresh an HttpPost, rather than a request (the refresh header is not intended for POSTS). I'd suggest as an alternative, that you change your process to be a request, which would result in only needing to change the invoking code (to a get) and changing the Report action to:

```
string operatorCode = Request.QueryString["txtOperator"];
```

this should give you the desired result, tho at the expense of the action now being a get rather than a post. You could also store the operatorCode in Session (tho this may not scale very well). The final option that I can see, would be to run an ajax request on a setInterval() and use that process to send a POST to the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing in temp session and then using it from there when you lost it?

```
 string operatorCode = Request.Form.GetValues("txtOperator")[0].ToString();
    TempData["operatorCode"] = operatorCode;

     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(operatorCode))
     {
        TempData["operatorCode"] = operatorCode;

         ViewBag.operatorName = (from e in db.employees
                          where e.operator_code == operatorCode
                          select e.name).Max().ToString();            

   ViewData["operatorCode"] = operatorCode;            

    var results =  db.lex_sp_Select_Paintline_FinRew_Operator(operatorCode);

    Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "10");

    return View(results.ToList());

     }
     else
     {
        var tempCode = TempData["operatorCode"]
        ViewData["operatorCode"] = tempCode;            

        var results =  db.lex_sp_Select_Paintline_FinRew_Operator(tempCode);

        Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "10");

        return View(results.ToList());
     }
```

Comment: I was trying to use tempdata as well but it's that first line that creates the error on refresh, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."